# I could not connect Strapi with MongoDB using Visual Studio Code. Please assist me in this

Tags: mongodb, strapi

[image]

And I am repeatedly getting the following error message:

[image]

Where is the problem? How do I connect strapi to MongoDD?

Comment: Image Link 1:https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xkb3o.png

Comment: Image Link 2: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wuUc.png Please check image 1 and 2 to see the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to first connect to MongoDB locally. Keep everything blank, or enter the values for your locally running instance of MongoDB. Then, you can retrieve the connection URL from Atlas or wherever, and then you need to edit your `config/database.js`:

```js
module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
    defaultConnection: 'default',
    connections: {
        default: {
            connector: 'mongoose',
            settings: {
                uri: env('DATABASE_URI')
            },
            options: {
                ssl: true
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Then, in your `.env` file:

```
DATABASE_URI=[CONNECTION_STRING_HERE]
```

Restart the server and you will be connected with your cloud instance of MongoDB.
If you still have issues, you can see the strapi docs: https://strapi.io/documentation/developer-docs/latest/guides/databases.html#install-on-atlas-mongodb-atlas.